# import keras disables multiprocessing

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing

Code is working fine, but as soon as i uncomment line #5 multiprocessing is not working anymore. 
I know that keras doesn't support to run in multiple processes but I want to run it in a main process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log')
logging.getLogger().setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
#import keras

def f():
    logging.info("Test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
```

Comment: What does "multiprocessing is not working" mean? Please be detailed

Comment: The code in function f doesn't get executed when 'import keras' is uncommented. No entry in logfile is made. I am using Windows 7.